# Ruby HTTP response html tag

Tags: ruby, http, post

I have a small problem in Ruby. I tried to POST some data to my web script and the response is the whole HTML page, but I need only value in div class="myclass"... How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an HTML parsing library [like nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to find the element you want within the HTML document and extract it. (You could probably work up a quick solution using regular expressions or some such, but a parsing library is much more robust for this purpose.)

Comment: I have this html
`<div id="main"><div class="msgerr">I can't find it, man.</div>....`
And i can't get the text even with nokogiri...

Comment: Here's an example of using Nokogiri to find a `div` with the class `msgerr`: https://gist.github.com/868488

Comment: Saved your life? You should read over your contracts more carefully! ;) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to one of the OP's comments. Droid said:

> I have this html `<div id="main"><div class="msgerr">I can't find it, man.</div>....` And i can't get the text even with nokogiri...

Here's how to do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = %q{<div id="main"><div class="msgerr">I can't find it, man.</div>}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('div.msgerr').text #=> "I can't find it, man."
```